# The optional parameter in the route does not work

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-9

I'm having a problem with the optional parameter; in particular I notice that it is not read in the link.

I explain in detail: in the view I have a table with several clients. In this table there is a column with the active projects for each customer (through the CLient_id foreign key present in the Projects table).

So what I want is that when I click on that client's number of active projects, it shows me these active projects.

**ROUTE:**

```js
Route::get('/project/index/{id?}', [ProjectController::class, 'index'])->name('project.index');
```

**ProjectController:**

```js
public function index($id = NULL)
    {   
        if($id){
            $projects = Project::where('client_id', $id)->get();
        } else {
            $projects = Project::all();
        }
        return view('project.index', compact('projects'));
    }
```

**View:**

```js
<tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>N. active projects</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($clients as $client)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $client->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $client->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $client->email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $client->address }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{route('project.index')}}" class="link-primary">{{ $client->projects_count }}</a></td>
                <td>
```

***When I click on the number of active projects of that client, it always takes me back to the index where ALL the projects are present.***

Comment: you have to pass id here                 <td><a href="{{route('project.index',$client->id)}}" class="link-primary">{{ $client->projects_count }}</a></td>

Comment: Where is your html or js logic? Most probably you are not passing `id` to the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter is working as expected. Change

```html
<td><a href="{{route('project.index')}}" class="link-primary">{{ $client->projects_count }}</a></td>
```

to

```html
<td><a href="{{route('project.index', ['id' => $client->id])}}" class="link-primary">{{ $client->projects_count }}</a></td>
```

to actually pass the `$id` to the controller.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I had missed this detail

Comment: Why are brackets [ ] used? Recently I've been learning Laravel

Comment: This is just an array. The `route` function takes an array as a second optional parameter.

Comment: OK perfect. Where can I find information related to this?

Comment: The [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/[Global_Namespace].html).

Comment: @Sarah The Laravel documentation has info on [Generating URLs To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)